# using validation pipe in nestjs gives me an classTransformer.plainToclass is not a function error

Tags: graphql, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

i am using `nestjs/graphql`, and i made a dto for a graphql mutation where i used class-validator options like `@IsString()` and `@IsBoolean()`. for this i installed `class-validator` and `class-transformer`. But when i do the mutation, it gives me an unheard error. i googled it, but nothing comes out.
the error is like this:

```
[Nest] 5872  - 2021. 11. 21. 오후 7:56:09   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] classTransformer.plainToClass is not a function
TypeError: classTransformer.plainToClass is not a function
    at ValidationPipe.transform (/home/inust33/ubereats-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:51:39)
    at /home/inust33/ubereats-backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/pipes/pipes-consumer.js:16:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

in playground, it shows me like this:
[graphql playground error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyZtm.png)

my dto looks like this:

```
@ArgsType()
export class createRestaurantDto {
  @Field((type) => String)
  @IsString()
  @Length(5, 10)
  name: string;

  @Field((type) => Boolean)
  @IsBoolean()
  isVegan: boolean;

  @Field((type) => String)
  @IsString()
  address: string;

  @Field((type) => String)
  @IsString()
  ownersName: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @IsString()
  categoryName: string;
}
```

the mutation i used this dto is this:

```
 @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async createRestaurant(
    @Args() createRestaurantDto: createRestaurantDto,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      await this.restaurantService.createRestaurant(createRestaurantDto);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

i did the validation pipe setting in main.ts like this:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

All I can get is without setting the `useGlobalPipes` option which is not what i want to do here, the mutation works out well.
could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 11):

problem solved.
due to recent update, class-transformer@0.5.0 makes an error when used in validationPipe of nestJS.

you should downgrade to class-transformer@0.4.0

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8637

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error with class-transformer@0.4.0

Updated to class-transformer@0.5.1 and it was solved.

I'm using Nest v8.0.0